# How to pass column name with function readtable in julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

```julia
using DataFrames
label = ["Data", "tempo", "RAh", "RAm", "RAs", "DEh", "DEm", "DEs"]
df    = readtable("mars.dat", separator = ' ',header = false, names = label)
```

I get the next error

```
MethodError: no method matching DataFrames.ParseOptions(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Bool, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool)
Closest candidates are:
  DataFrames.ParseOptions(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{S<:String,1}, ::Array{T<:String,1}, ::Array{T<:String,1}, ::Bool, ::Array{Symbol,1}, ::Array{T,1} where T, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::AbstractArray{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool) where {S<:String, T<:String} at /home/juser/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:9

Stacktrace:
 [1] #readtable#84(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::IOStream, ::Int64) at /home/juser/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:843
 [2] (::DataFrames.#kw##readtable)(::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::IOStream, ::Int64) at ./<missing>:0
 [3] #readtable#85(::Bool, ::Char, ::Array{Char,1}, ::Char, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{String,1}, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Bool, ::Char, ::Bool, ::Int64, ::Array{Int64,1}, ::Bool, ::Symbol, ::Bool, ::Bool, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::String) at /home/juser/.julia/v0.6/DataFrames/src/dataframe/io.jl:945
 [4] (::DataFrames.#kw##readtable)(::Array{Any,1}, ::DataFrames.#readtable, ::String) at ./<missing>:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for readtable, it seems it expects a vector of symbols, not a vector of strings:

> names::Vector{Symbol} – Use the values in this array as the names for all columns instead of or in lieu of the names in the file's header.

You can convert your vector of strings to a vector of symbols (assuming your strings are valid names) with a list comprehension, e.g.

```
labelSymbols = [Symbol(i) for i in label];
```

and pass this to your names parameter.

---

<sub>Disclaimer: I have not tested to see if this works as I don't have access to the `mars.dat` file. I'm just reading the docs and pointing out the most likely problem.</sub>

Comment: Sorry for making an annoying remark here, but is the format `labelSymbols = Symbol.(label)` not more ideomatic in Julia?

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard hah, good point. I don't think of broadcasting syntax as being more or less idiomatic than list comprehension syntax per se, but admittedly in my mind I thought of this semantically as "from each string element generate a symbol" rather than "apply the symbol constructor elementwise"; I didn't even think of this as a broadcasting operation to begin with :p